# Change two div contents on mouseover image in separate div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseover, getelementbyid

I'm trying to change two (preview) `div` elements with `mouseover` on a button-image with a link.

One of the preview-divs will show an image, which I would like to have linked to a specific site

The button-image also has a `mouseover` function class in CSS.

I might add that there will be multiple images to use this function, each spaced with an own div and a class, which i believe isn't semantically correct as it should be when using an usorted list (but that i will worry about later)

Also I'd like to add I'm new to scripting but eager to learn.

On `mouseout` or `click` is not important, the current (preview) contents may remain as on last `mouseover`.

Currently the changing of the preview divs content works by adding document.getElementById to the anchor and the img separately to each button as stated in the following messy code , but i am looking for a cleaner approach like something with javascript or jquery and using vars and making the preview image clickable and linked to the previewed site
**[EDIT:]This code DOES work for making the preview image a link[/EDIT]**

It would be really great if i could load each preview image and text from an external file

```
<div class="btn">

 <a href="http://www.previewed_site.com" target="_blank"
 onmouseover="document.getElementById('preview_text_content')
 .innerHTML = 'a short preview description here';">

  <img onmouseover="document.getElementById('preview_img_content')
  .innerHTML = '<a href=\'http://www.previewed_site.com\'>
  <img src=\'preview.jpg\' /></a>';" src="btn.png" width="100px"
  height="40px" alt="mysite.com" /> 

 </a>
</div>
```

The CSS for the btn mouseover (which works like i want but added here for reference):

```
.btn {
    position relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height:40px;
}
.btn a { 
    display:block; 
    width:100px; 
    height:40px; 
    z-index: 100;
}
.btn a:hover { 
    background: url(btn_hover.png);
}
```

Some words of advice or some links to example codes would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go..using jquery...

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn">
   <a href="http://www.previewed_site.com" target="_blank" >
     <img src="btn.png" width="100px" height="40px" alt="mysite.com" /> 
   </a>
</div>
```

with jquery, you can use [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) function on a selected element..jquery documentation for selector is [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   //recommened you to use script inside document.ready always
$(".btn  a").mouseover(function(){  //selecting element with "<a>" tag inside an element of class "btn"
     $('#preview_text_content') .html('a short preview description here'); //getting an element with an id "preview_text_content" and repalcing its html with jquery html() ;
})

$(".btn  img").mouseover(function(){
  $('#preview_img_content').html('<a href=\'http://www.previewed_site.com\'><img src=\'preview.jpg\' /></a>'); //similar as above

});
});
```

---

**UPDATED**

dynamic loading image n text...using [data attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

**HTML**

```
//first image
<a href="http://www.previewed_site.com" target="_blank" data-text_content="a short preview description here">
   <img src="btn.png" width="100px" height="40px" alt="mysite.com" data-img_content="preview.jpg"/>
</a>
//second image
<a href="http://www.previewed_site.com" target="_blank" data-text_content="a short preview description here 2">
   <img src="btn.png" width="100px" height="40px" alt="mysite.com" data-img_content="preview2.jpg"/>
</a>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $(".btn  a").mouseover(function(){  
   $('#preview_text_content') .html($(this).data('text_content')); 
 })

$(".btn  img").mouseover(function(){ 
   var imgContent='<a href=\'http://www.previewed_site.com\'><img src=\''+$(this).data('img_content') +'\' /></a>';
   $('#preview_img_content').html(imgContent); 

 });
});
```

---

**OR**

you can always use functions to clear your codes and making it understandable..

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn">

 <a href="http://www.previewed_site.com" target="_blank" onmouseover="linkMouseoverFunction()">

  <img onmouseover="imgMouseoverFunction()" src="btn.png" width="100px" height="40px" alt="mysite.com" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 function linkMouseoverFunction()
 {
    document.getElementById('preview_text_content').innerHTML = 'a short preview description here';
 }

function imgMouseoverFunction()
{
   document.getElementById('preview_img_content').innerHTML = '<a href=\'http://www.previewed_site.com\'><img src=\'preview.jpg\' /></a>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, the code is clear and understandable, i used the jquery and removed some bits to get the linkMouseOverFunction applied only to the anchor
i also added ID's to the button divs so i could give them seperate preview texts and images when hovered
the preview image is now correctly linked too, that was a CSS z-index mistake 
Any pointers on how to load the all preview images an texts from one external file using jquery?

Comment: Of course: say i have 4 buttons, each have to show a different preview text and image, can i put all these images and text in an seperate file, say preview_contents.htm and get the variables(?) from this file, so i dont need to edit the script when updating the preview texts/images

Comment: updated answer using data attributes of HTML 5... hav a look that is just an example of how u can do it... let me know if any problem...

Comment: Not exactly what i meant, but i can sure use this with some modifications, thanks, your codes learned me a lot!